# Batch rename file invert position name

Tags: batch-file, rename

My files have names like:

```
andromeda_01.02.19.xlsx
```

I need to change it to:

```
 andromeda_20190201.xlsx
```

Removing the dots, using a batch file.

I could only isolate the date, using batch:

```
@echo off
RENAME "andromeda_*xlsx" "//////////////////*.xlsx"
```

Can someone help?

Comment: So, you have filenames called `andromeda_dd.mm.yy.xlsx` and you want to rename them to `andromeda_yyymmdd`? Or do you have filenames like `*_dd.mm.yy.xlsx` and you want to rename them to `*_yyymmdd`? Please clarify that. In case you are in the second way, does the filename before the `_` contain spaces?

Comment: Do you insist on doing this with a Batch file, or would a PowerShell script be acceptable? Batch isn't really suited for the kind of string manipulation you want to do; PowerShell is much better for it.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Would you be so kind and inform me how exactly batch is not suited for this kind of string manipulation?

Comment: @double-beep     yes, i have filenames called andromeda_dd.mm.yy.xlsx and  want to rename them to andromeda_yyyymmdd.

Comment: I reiterate my question above: Would a PowerShell script be acceptable, or do you insist on it being a Batch file?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin don't ask! Provide just a solution for future readers!

Comment: @double-beep - PowerShell doesn't answer the question _as asked_; that's why I inquire as to acceptability. If I were to see a request that doesn't explicitly ask for a specific language I might well post a PowerShell soluition.

Comment: Are the two-digit years all 20-something, or also 19-? if the latter, how to know what century applies?

Comment: @aschipfl - I generally assume the current year as the "cross the century" line - if the yy is greater than the current year, it's previous century, otherwise it's current century.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, this makes perfect sense in most applications, I think. Anyway, my comment was aimed at the OP in case this is something they didn't yet think of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `andromeda_dd.mm.yy.xlsx` files, you should use:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=._" %%A IN ('dir /B /A-D andromeda_*.xlsx') do (
    rename "andromeda_%%A.%%B.%%C.xlsx" "andromeda_20%%C%%B%%A.xlsx"
)
```

Comment: Because you use 2 for loops where 1 could have been used. You also set delayedexpansion where not used, you also manually set a date variable, what if the file is `andromeda_09.01.95.xlsx` You cannot assume all files will be year `20**`

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Not at all, I commented.. Like he said, you fix your mistakes, then we remove the downvote, isn't it?

Comment: Still loads of stuff wrong here, I am amazed OP marked it as correct as it cannot even work as is.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin you sure? have you actually tested the good solution?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - It worked when I tried it; if it's not working for you, can you provide an analysis?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, `tokens=2-4` will will not assign to `andromeda` so `%%~fa` is actually `C:\somepath\01` instead of file name. Also, tokens `2-4` are actually only 3 tokens `a-c` in this case so `%%d` cannot exist.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin lastly, if a file exists with the name starting `andromeda_*.xls` no matter the string after `_` it will rename it, so all newly renamed files will also be renamed with a corrupt string. So as a final analysis, it is impossible to have worked when you tried it, it simply cannot work. We'll see OP back here in a day or 2.

Comment: I think by my rep you should see that I know how downvoting works and I am not going to make this an extended disussion. So _"You don't downvote the answers when they are working"_ it was impossible to have worked for the above mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This will ensure that we do not rename files already renamed. i.e only rename `andromeda_dd.mm.yy.xls` and wil not rename `andromeda_yyyymmddxls` Additionally, we will check if a file ro rename to does not exist already and tell you about it if it does. Also, this assumes the century 20yy as there are no other indicators in your filename proving another:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d andromeda_*.*.*.xlsx') do (
    set "manip=%%~nj"
    if exist "%%i_20!manip:~6,2!!manip:~0,2!!manip:~3,2!%%~xj" (
        echo file %%i_20!manip:~6,2!!manip:~0,2!!manip:~3,2!%%~xj already Exists!
     ) else (
        rename %%i_%%j %%i_20!manip:~6,2!!manip:~0,2!!manip:~3,2!%%~xj
  )
)
```